# lensflare disppearing and rendering too slow

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to get lensflare to work in ThreeJS.
It seem to function okay when there is distance to camera but if I camera is moved to about 50 units or less distance to lensflare the flare disappears! Why?

**Update:**
After further investigation I noticed that lensflare works fine in webgl_lensflares.html example. The problem is when I try to add it to ThreeJS Editor. Adding it to Editor causes 3 problems:

1. Rendering becomes painfully slow.
2. When I rotate the scene the lensflare rotates fine, but when I move the scene the lensflare moved the opposite direction.
3. If I put the lensflare at (0,0,0) it disappears when I get too close to it, but if I put it in locations away from origin such as (0,10,0) it doesn't have that problem.

Here is the code that I added to Editor in Viewport.js:

```
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var textureFlare0 = textureLoader.load("textures/lensflare/lensflare0.png");
    var flareColor = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    flareColor.setHSL(0.55, 0.9, 0.5 + 0.5);
    var lensFlare = new THREE.LensFlare(textureFlare0, 100, 1.0, THREE.AdditiveBlending, flareColor);
    lensFlare.position.set(0, 0, -10);
    scene.add(lensFlare);
```

Comment: What lens flare? Are you using a THREE.js example? Or did you write/download/copy a custom post-process shader? Please include details like what you have, what you tried to correct the problem, and example code that will help us reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: I'm using this Three.js example: webgl_lensflares.html

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem you're seeing. That said, the code for updating the lens flares is in the example, so you can watch what happens when the camera moves around. Compare the results of the camera being at a distance, versus the camera being very close like you describe. My guess is that one of the result values is turning into `NaN` which is causing the flare positions to become undefined.

Comment: you should probably provide some code, impossible to say what is wrong. One thing to check is what value you set as the "near clipping plane" for the camera ```THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 1, 1000 );```, do you have a high value as the 3rd argument to this constuctor?

Comment: Thank you both for trying to help. Please see the updated question+code above.

Comment: Please copy your answer into an actual answer and accept it, so others can see that you have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to all my 3 problems:

1. Netbean debugger was slowing down the rendering. Once I turned off Netbean debugger it became much faster. I still notice flare rendering slows down rendering a little but it's at least usable now.
2. The reason lensfare would move the opposition direction was because I passed 1.0 as its 3rd parameter. Should've been 0.0
3. The reason why at (0,0,0) I don't see the flare is because there is another shape located on that position. Apparently flare is not visible if it is position insider another shape. I had wrongly assumed that flare is rendered last and hence always visible.